# How batch api for gmail can be used for listing gmail?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, batch-request

Want to make a batch request for listing that can bring sender and title of each message along with it in gmail api. how can I make a batch request for it? Is it possible to make a batch request using postman?

As part of batch request, how batch request can be requested ?

how can I use batch request for above requirement endpoints?

```
As part of batch request as per google doc ,
POST /batch/farm/v1 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_foobarbaz
Content-Length: total_content_length

--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <item1:12930812@barnyard.example.com>

GET /farm/v1/animals/pony

--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <item2:12930812@barnyard.example.com>

PUT /farm/v1/animals/sheep
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: part_content_length
If-Match: "etag/sheep"

{
  "animalName": "sheep",
  "animalAge": "5"
  "peltColor": "green",
}

--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <item3:12930812@barnyard.example.com>

GET /farm/v1/animals
If-None-Match: "etag/animals"

--batch_foobarbaz--
```

as per my requirement, I don't get how doc request can be modified?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.  Yes you can probably do this in postman but its going to be hard as with batching you can send up to 100 requests and your going to have to type out the body of the batch request manually.  Personally i would use a server sided programming language.

Comment: @DalmTo question has been modified

Comment: @DalmTo as per doc, it contains farm in post endpoint. Is it used for what purpose ?

Comment: Have you **read** the documentation page? Dont just copy the code read it.  You need to change the requests to point to the actual request you want to make.  /farm/v1/animals/pony is not an api call to Gmail..

Comment: @DalmTo I have read it. I am talking about batch post endpoint POST /batch/farm/v1 HTTP/1.1. If it is gmail doc, how come farm in that case ?

Comment: You dont. Its a dummy example.  batch /batch/farm/v1 is NOT an endpoint. YOu would change it to the endpoint you want to use for your api.  This example code is used for all of the Google APIs they couldnt post gmail over on YOutube api could they?

Comment: @DalmTo ok,got it. it is for demo purpose but i don't get how can I modify endpoint in my case so that I get a batch response in gmail list api response.

Comment: You wouldn't send requests to the 
Users.messages: list end point you would be sending the requests to the 
Users.messages: get endpoint.   Your batching the get requests. You will need to make one call to gmail.messages.list get all your ids.  Then build up your batch request with each of the Ids to to be sent to 
Users.messages: get.  Batch isnt going to help you not need to do the gets your still going to have to get each message individually your just only making one HTTP call

Comment: @DalmTo yes, for that building batch , I am talking about batch endpoint  for ex,POST /batch/farm/v1 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_foobarbaz
Content-Length: total_content_length In getting gmail get batch request how endpoint would be modified?

Comment: Check my anwser POST /batch/gmail/v1 HTTP/1.1  <-- Your making a request to the Gmail api.  Its gmail v1 batching endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make a batch request for it?

By using the batching end point [Batching](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch)

> Is it possible to make a batch request using postman?

Yes postman can handle this call.  But you will have to manually create the body which considering can contain 100 requests is going to be very time consuming and pron to error IMO.

> As part of batch request, how batch request can be requested ?

By sending a HTTP Post where the body contains each of the single requests you are requesting data for.

> how can I use batch request for above requirement endpoints?

You can do it with postman or any other programming language that can handle http post calls.

each line `GET /farm/v1/animals` in the body contains the request that you wish to make to the api in your case it would be something like `users/me/messages/1`.

You will need to call users messages.list first get a list of all the message ids that you want to get information for. Then build up your batch request to the user.messages to get and request each message.  Batching will not mean that you dont need to send a get request for each message batching just saves you the extra http calls made by sending each get request.

```
POST /batch/gmail/v1 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_foobarbaz
Content-Length: total_content_length
Accept-Encoding: application/gzip

--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http


GET gmail/v1/users/me/messages/16d24956228a98c4
Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8

--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http


GET gmail/v1/users/me/messages/16d24956228a98c4
Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8

--batch_foobarbaz--
```

Comment: @DalmTo I have tried above request. It gives Error 400 Bad Request.

Comment: You probably didnt set up the headers right or you have the wrong url.

Comment: Still getting 400, RequestBody:                                                                           
 --batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/16d243eebef48c9a
Accept: application/json; 

--batch_foobarbaz
Content-Type: application/http
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/16d242d21af1a2ef
Accept: application/json; 

--batch_foobarbaz--

Comment: @DalmTo Response : `--batch_vLy1GSRjmBo_AAQUpNtQKSE
Content-Type: application/http
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 12 Sep 2019 09:30:21 GMT
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "endpointConstraintMismatch",
    "message": "The request did not match the specified API.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "path"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The request did not match the specified API."
 }
}
--batch_vLy1GSRjmBo_AAQUpNtQKSE--
`

Comment: The request did not match the specified API. <--- your urls are wrong check them. I tested this in postman and it works fine.

Comment: can you send your tested url?

Comment: the same way I have requested with current working token though getting issue. If you don't mind can you share your postman collection link.

Comment: **Working solution is here** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343365/gmail-rest-api-batch-support-for-getting-messages